# How to make a nice partial horizontal line in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Creating a paper form, with lines like this:  Name______ Date_______,
except I want nice continuous lines that look like full horizontal lines from the paragraph menu.

The lines need to start at the next character position, with the last line ending at the right margin.

This is really easy in WordPerfect - with the proper underline setting in the Font menu, all you do is click <kbd>U</kbd> for underline, and then use the <kbd>spacebar</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd> key, or flush right <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to the margin.

In WP, you can also select an area of spaces or tabs, and then click on the "U" pad. These lines also behave nicely when editing.  The only way I could find to get it right in Word was to create a document with lines in WP, save to docx, and copy and paste the lines once in Word.

[image]

Comment: What is exactly wrong with that document?  Could you post some screenshot?

Comment: Just copy and paste this, adjust as needed: `________________________________________________`

Comment: The document is OK now, but I was unable to create it purely in MS Word. I could do paragraph horizontal line that makes a full width line, a few mm below the text, underscore one space at a time, but various lines don't end at the same place, or graphic lines that are hard to make regular.  Here's a link to screenshot: http://s224.photobucket.com/user/jbuysell/media/Screenshot%2053.png.html?filters[user]=57287631&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with single lines of text:

1. Set a right-aligned tab at your right margin value with option 4 for underscore selected for the tab properties.
2. Type your text, then an underscore character followed by a tab character.  Go back and select your underscore character only and change its font properties so its spacing is condensed by 10pt (Advanced tab of Font dialog).

[image]